# Maven Assembly : How to generate a zip file for each environment ?

Tags: maven-3, development-environment, production-environment, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a static project with html, js, css and conf files like this :

```
project 
       - static
            - conf
                 conf-int.json
                 conf-rec.json
                 conf-prd.json
            -js 
            -html
            -images 
       - pom.xml 
       - assemblyDescriptor.xml
```

Here is my assembly descriptor :

```
 <id>zip</id>
    <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>static/conf/</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Here is my build conf in pom.xml

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>trigger-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
```

I want to generate my zip with either  conf-int.json or  conf-rec.json or  conf-prd.json corresponding to differents environments i have. If it were a java project i would use profil maven with profil and/or classifier. But i don't know how to generate a zip file for each environment with maven-assembly. Could you give me some advice please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple execution defined in your assembly plugin (each with distinct execution id and different assembly descriptor file). In the respective descriptor you define which file to include.